# count file lines always returns 1 - mac OSx

Tags: php, file, count

I am new to php.
I am trying to count the lines on a txt document, but this always returns me 1 (despite the fact that there are a lot more lines in the file):

```
<?php
  $file = "example.txt";
  $lines = count(file($file));
  print "There are $lines lines in $file";
?>
```

Why do you think this is?
As a side note, I am using Mac OSx.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = "example.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php ):

```
Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files 
either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings 
run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.
```

That may be the cause of it. Hard to say without more information.

Comment: I inserted this: ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings",true); but still does not work!! I also think that it is something related to this. What other information would you need?

Answer (score 0):

This will use less memory, since it doesn't load the whole file into memory:

```
$file="largefile.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

fgets loads a single line into memory (if the second argument $length is omitted it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line, which is what we want). This is still unlikely to be as quick as using something other than PHP, if you care about wall time as well as memory usage.

The only danger with this is if any lines are particularly long (what if you encounter a 2GB file without line breaks?). In which case you're better off doing slurping it in in chunks, and counting end-of-line characters:

```
$file="largefile.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
  $linecount = $linecount + substr_count($line, PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($handle);

echo $linecount;
```

I prefer the second code if I want to know only lines in the particular file